# jQuery AJAX Get not connecting to PHP $_GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, get

When I call ajax via some search or filter functionality I've written in, the full list is improperly returned without the filters. I've been able isolate so far to find that the data in the ajax call is not reaching the PHP $_GET variable. Below is the jQuery capturing data for and creating the ajax call that runs initially on page load and when a user searches or filters:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var attempt = 1;
  var scholarship_search;
  var scholarship_region;
  var scholarship_state;
  var queryData;
  var load_posts = function(queryData) {
    $.ajax({
      type : 'GET', //'POST'
      url : '/wp-content/themes/campuspride2015/lib/scholarship-db.php',
      data : queryData,
      dataType : 'html',
      success : function(data, s, o) {
        $('#scholarship-results-container').append(data);
        console.log(attempt +' : '+ s +' : '+ queryData);
        attempt ++;
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * ajax call from search
  **/
  $('#scholarship-search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disable the normal click

    // gather the query data
    sch_search = $('#scholarship-search').val(); //coming from an input field

    queryData = {
      scholarship_search_submit : true,
      scholarship_search : sch_search
    };

    load_posts(queryData); // ajax page load
  });

  $('#scholarship-filter-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disable the normal click

    // gather the query data
    sch_filter_region = $('#scholarship_region').val(); // select drop down
    sch_filter_state = $('#scholarship_state').val(); // select drop down

    queryData = {
      scholarship_filter_submit : true,
      scholarship_region : sch_filter_region
      scholarship_state : sch_filter_state
    };

    load_posts(queryData); // ajax page load
  });

  load_posts(queryData);

});
```

And the following is the PHP script that should capture the request and returns the page data, but for some reason the ajax $.get(); is not reaching the php $_GET.

```html
// WP access
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

// Variables that dictate the results to be shown
$search_submit = (isset($_GET['scholarship_search_submit']) ? $_GET['scholarship_search_submit'] : 0);
$filter_submit = (isset($_GET['scholarship_filter_submit']) ? $_GET['scholarship_filter_submit'] : 0);

/**
 * Query for Scholarships
**/

/** Check for search parameters **/
if($search_submit) {
  // run query (which is not running...)
}

/** query based on filters **/
elseif($filter_submit) {
  // run query (which is also not running...)
}

/** Initial page viewing, show all **/
else {
  // this is running, because the $_GET variable is not being populated
} ?>
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2/25/16**

Got it solved, guys. the `queryData` variable needed to be broken down into key.value pairs in order to be sent and picked up. i.e. `data : { scholarship_search : queryData.value } etc...

Thanks for your input, everyone.

Comment: making request when page loads but `queryData` is undefined at that point ... last line of js  `load_posts(queryData);`

Comment: Right. This is exactly my problem. :-/

Comment: well what are you expecting it to do on page load? Either set defaults in javascript or php if $_GET is empty ... `if(empty($_GET)){loadDefaults();}`

Comment: after that the ones in the form submits seem ok within the js

Comment: The default, or final "else" in the if/else sequence is to `load_posts()` with no data sent to the server, so it just pulls them all in. I'm seeing the AJAX complete via `console.log()`, but I'm not seeing the data in the AJAX request actually reach the PHP $_GET at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the way the data is sent to ajax.
`queryData.value1` and so on should be replaced with new variable names you give to each of the items.

```js
var load_posts = function(queryData) {
    $.ajax({
      type : 'GET', //'POST'
      url : '/wp-content/themes/campuspride2015/lib/scholarship-db.php',
      data : {
        scholarship_search_submit : queryData.value1,
        scholarship_search : queryData.value2,
        scholarship_filter_submit : queryData.value3,
        scholarship_region : queryData.value4,
        scholarship_state : queryData.value5
      },
      dataType : 'html',
      success : function(data, s, o) {
        $('#scholarship-results-container').append(data);
        console.log(attempt +' : '+ s +' : '+ queryData);
        attempt ++;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The query data for the ajax call from search, for example, should be

```
queryData = {
  'scholarship_search_submit' : true,
  'scholarship_search' : sch_search
};
```

The added quotes are the important part. Then when you call

```
load_posts(queryData);
```

the php script will receive the `$_GET` variables you intend.

Comment: quotes are optional for javascript object keys that don't have special characters

Comment: That makes sense to me, but now I'm getting an error, unexpected " ' ". I suppose underscores are actually accepted. I tried double quotes too.

Answer (score 0):

You try to pass `scholarship_filter_submit` and `scholarship_search_submit` as booleans but they will reach server as strings - 'true' or 'false'. So you cannot check their values later in php as `if($search_submit)` and `elseif($filter_submit) {`. You should use `if($search_submit==='true')` and `elseif($filter_submit === 'true') {`.

Comment: I would try to replace `true` to `1` and `false` to `0` when sending from client and check for those values server side. I had same problem once.

Answer (score 0):

Check out chrome dev tools or use fiddler to see your network traffic. This will be step one to make sure your Ajax request URL is correctly formatted.

Comment: I'm logging w/console.log() so I see that an `[Object Object]` is returning, but it's still not reaching the php $_GET for some reason.